# A brief description of a plausible and possible candidate for Quantum Gravity

Tags: string-theory, quantum-gravity, supergravity, theory-of-everything, loop-quantum-gravity

I wanted to know the specifics(essence) of a particular theory that is present for [quantum gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gravity) (QG),and which seems to have the best potential. I am no expert on field theories and QG, cause otherwise I would have understood the answer for the same, online. I would appreciate a simple and detailed explanation of special attributes of a specific theory and its possibility of being a potential candidate for QG.

I did read the short part on QG in the book,[General Relativity: an Einstein Centenary Survey](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/General_Relativity_an_Einstein_Centenary.html?id=pxA4AAAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y)
But it was way beyond my current knowledge of comprehending advance theories.

I am asking this as I wanted to find an answer to another question of mine which is:

> A classical object spaghettifies inside a blackhole and would eventually break into atoms. Now these atoms would disintegrate into electrons and nucleons. Would they too not break down into quarks and leptons? This can be analysed by the QM-ical interaction between the BH and the particle, but which candidate would provide the closest results?

[Trajectory of safe descent into a black hole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/287685/trajectory-of-safe-descent-into-a-black-hole)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/117147/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks! But that question is too broad and specific around the two theories, what I am asking is limited to the candidates and their fate as time passed.

Comment: @NaveenBalaji, hey, I'm sorry, but I think this question is a tad too broad. Try looking at [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266744/what-is-the-difference-between-quantum-gravity-loop-quantum-gravity-quantum-ge/266788#266788) question/answer, which has a few theories of quantum gravity (and which was also closed as too broad).

Comment: @heather Thanks a lot! I asked this as I was in search for an answer to: what would happen to an electron inside a quantum mechanical black hole? I had asked a question on SE regarding the probability of a trajectory of safe descent into a BH, and many encouraged me to ask about the candidates for QG as dot a classical object spaghettifies inside a blackhole and would eventually break into atoms. Now these atoms would disintegrate into electrons and nucleons. Would not they too break down into quarks and leptons? This can be analysed by the QM-ical interaction between the BH and the particle.

Comment: @NaveenBalaji, ah, very nice! An interesting question! They were right. We don't know because a quantum theory of gravity is needed to understand what would happen to quantum mechanical objects in places where general relativity is needed to explain what is going on. So far, we don't have a quantum theory of gravity. I might recommend looking around on wikipedia for summaries of the various quantum theories of gravity, and you could also ask in physics chat about them, or on here if you have any specific questions. Good luck!

Comment: @heather@Qmechanic I have added more content to the question to make it more specific.

Comment: @NaveenBalaji, and thank you for being willing to add that information! Not all users are like that. Unfortunately, it still can't be reopened. Let me explain why. That second part is a question that has already been asked, and so that doesn't really make *this* question any more answerable, though it certainly does provide some good context! I'd suggest maybe asking about what features a quantum theory of gravity should have, and see how that goes, and maybe doing a little googling yourself to narrow down the question. Here, give me a moment and I'll see what I can find in terms of resources.

Comment: @NaveenBalaji, try [this overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gravity) of quantum gravity and various theories on wikipedia.

Comment: @heather I have linked the book I read on QG. Pg581, part one if I remember right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47283/discussion-between-heather-and-naveen-balaji).

Comment: @heather I have made the question more specific addressing an unique issue, would you reconsider opening this question?

Comment: @NaveenBalaji, I have nominated the question for reopening; it'll need three more reopen votes to be reopened, but I think there's a good chance it will be reopened.

Comment: @heather Sure that's great to hear. Please do suggest question edits, if any to improve the clarity of my question.